# Using ProcDump to obtain the dump of a service?

Tags: service, windows-services, procdump

Does anybody know if its possible/ how to use ProcDump to obtain the dump of a windows service? The command I want to run is like this:

```
ProcDump -e -mp -x myservice.exe mydump.dmp
```

However I get the **Cannot Start Service from command line or debugger** message. Does anybody know if there is a way around this?

Comment: OK After I bit of playing around I found out how to do this, the command I needed was:
    Procdump -e -mp 14312 mydump.dmp

where 14312 is the process id of the service, you can find this in task manager in the services tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK After I bit of playing around I found out how to do this, the command I needed was: `Procdump -e -mp 14312 mydump.dmp` where `14312` is the process id of the service, you can find this in task manager in the services tab.

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question, but unfortunately the answer doesn't help me. The service crashes right after it starts, and calling `Procdump -e -mp 14312 mydump.dmp` is too late at this stage. Any alternatives?

Comment: You could write sleep in code and make the executable wait until you can attach procdump.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is running into this, my usual is to run:

```
procdump.exe -ma -i C:\Dumps
```

This will register procdump as the Just-in-Time (AeDebug) debugger, and should create a dump for any crashing process on the system.

I've found "casting a wide net" yields a better result, compared with configuring a dump for the specific process name or PID.

Comment: Thanks, this catch-all solution works great. The command `procdump.exe -ma -i` is what finally helped me capture stack overflow crashes. All other commands resulted in a "Dump count not reached" message and it wouldn't dump the crash for my .NET Core 3.1 Windows Service. I was then able to load the dump in Visual Studio and when I ran the dump it immediately breakpointed on the line of code that caused the stack overflow.

Answer (score -2):

There is another option that allows you to dump exceptions even on windows service startup. With help of ["Image File Execution Options"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/xperf/image-file-execution-options) you can configure procdump as you service debugger.

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\{your service executable name. f.e. notepad.exe}" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "{procdump path}\procdump -ma -accepteula -e 1 -t -n 10 -x {dumps output folder}" /f
```

Don't forget to replace curly brackets with your values.
Please check the meaning of the procdump command line parameters, -ma, -e 1, -t, -n 10 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump)

To uninstall procdump:

```
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\{your service executable name. f.e. notepad.exe}" /va /f
```

Comment: this will start procdump itself as service process, and SCM will error on timeout